# Converting console application to GUI

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, user-interface, c++-cli

I found a C++ code to convert Latitude/Langitude to UTM coordinate.

The code is [here](http://ereimer.net/programs/LatLong-UTM.cpp).

I would like to use .NET GUI (windows Forms) instead of the console screen.

Now instead of entering the value `22.2 33.3` for example in console, I would read it from a `textBox`. and then call the conversion function.

The problem that I faced is I don't know what parameters should I pass to the function

```
`CvtLine(int C, char**V, char*p)`
```

which is called from the main function of console application:

### Code

```
int main(int argc, char**argv){                         //2010-08-11: was void main(...
   char buf[256]; char*p; int L,ac; char*av[129];               //vars for reading stdin
   cout<<setiosflags(ios::fixed);                       //decided against including ios::showpoint
   Fmt=fUT4|fLLD|fLLDM;                             //default for Fmt, if not specified by input
   --argc; ++argv;                              //remove spurious first element of argv array
   while(argc && memcmp(argv[0],"--",2)==0){                    //handle leading options: --Outputformat, --test, --help
      if     (isdigit(argv[0][2]))      Fmt=atoi(argv[0]+2);        //for --<DIGIT>, parse Outputformat into Fmt
      else if(strcmp(argv[0],"--test")==0)  {Testcases(); return 0;}    //for --test, run testcases & exit
      else                  {Usage(); return 0;}        //for --help, show Usage & exit
      --argc; ++argv;
   }
   if(argc==0)  while(cin.getline(buf,256), cin.good()){            //0 args, read stdin converting each line
      p=buf; ac=0;
      while(1){ while(*p&&strchr(" \t",*p))++p; if(*p==0||*p=='#')break; av[ac++]=p; while(*p&&!strchr(" \t#",*p))++p;} //break line into whitespace-separated words
      if(ac>=2&&ac<=4) CvtLine(ac,av,p);                    //line with 2|3|4 words, convert and print
      else if(ac==0)   cout<<buf<<"\n";                     //line with no words, echo the line (comments)
      else             cout<<"==invalid number-of-words: "<<buf<<"\n";      //anything else is invalid, produce errmsg
   }
   else if(argc>=2&&argc<=4)    CvtLine(argc,argv,"");              //2|3|4 args, convert and print
   else             Usage();                    //argc other than 0|2|3 is invalid, show Usage
   return 0;                                    //2010-08-11: added when void became illegal
}
```

Comment: Read the docs for `CvtLine` and pass params as it describes.

Comment: This was a bad question. A better one would have been to ask "How would I convert a Lat/Long to UMT"?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the .NET Spatial Reference and Projection Engine library. 
http://projnet.codeplex.com/

> **.NET Spatial Reference and Projection Engine**
>   Proj.NET performs point-to-point coordinate conversions between geodetic
>   coordinate systems for use in fx. Geographic Information Systems (GIS)
>   or GPS applications.

It their FAQ, there is a code sample on converting between systems. 
[Projecting points from one coordinate system to another](http://projnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreateProjection&referringTitle=FAQ)